# How to get original password from BCryptPasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring, passwords, bcrypt

I'm using spring security for my application. When a user register first time, their passwords are encrypted with `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
```

Now, in case of password changing, users enter their current password and I need to check if this current password is same against the encrypted password that is saved in the database.

I know it is not possible to generate two same encrypted hash with same string with `BCryptPasswordEncoder`. So probably only way to compare the passwords if they are same is to get the original password that is saved in the database and compare with the current entered password.

So, is there any way to compare the passwords or to get the original password from the database saved hashed password?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to only check the raw password against the encoded password in the db. For example,

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String p = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("SomeCoolPassword");
System.out.println(bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches("SomeCoolPassword", p));
```

Comment: Great solution, but in my case it is realy slow. If use such way of password verification(anywhery, dorin 'login' etc) such verification took 84% (!!!) of whole execution time(tested with profiler), need to imrove it in some way.(surely bcrypt is slow by design, but looks like that check is not optimized)

Comment: @AlexEfimov, I would be interested to see actual times and configs rather than a % of total execution time. Reason being, 84% of a relatively insignificant amount of time is also insignificant. It is true that this particular task is slow but performance and security are opposing forces/requirements and your specific requirements may demand a troublesome trade off . I use this exact code in a few web apps for login and haven't had an issue with it. [Also, have a look at this accepted answer for some info](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17207/recommended-of-rounds-for-bcrypt).

Comment: Question is 'how to get original', not 'how to compare'. I don't know why people like to answer on not set questions.

Comment: @parzival, I don't understand the issue. Yes, the title is - *"How to get original password from BCryptPasswordEncoder"* but the contents of the question includes - *"So, is there any way to compare the passwords or to get the original password from the database saved hashed password?"* Additionally, it was accepted by op, so I think it's important to look at the whole post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `passwordEncoder` doesn't create same hashes, but you can compare them, and if it was generated from the same string, it will return true. Check my example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        List<String> passwords = Arrays.asList(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("testPassword"),
                bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("testPassword"),
                bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("testPassword"),
                bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("testPassword"));

        passwords.stream()
                .filter(e -> bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches("testPassword", e))
                .forEach(e -> System.out.println(true));
    }
```

}

and i get 4 `true`.